# Plotting a logisitc curve in R for randomly created samples

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I want to plot a logisitc curve for my randomly created samples. I tried using the basic formula but I'm getting an error as below

```
Error in lines.formula(y ~ ., df1, col = "green4", lwd = 2) : 
  cannot handle more than one 'x' coordinate
```

My code:

```
fit <- glm(y ~ ., data = train_set, family = "binomial")
pred <- predict(fit, newdata = test_set, type = "response")
plot(y ~., data=df1, col="red4")
lines(y ~., df1, col="green4", lwd=2)
```

The above follows after fitting a logit model.

Comment: What do you want on the x-axis? If you have used more than one independent variable, you will have to select one.  You can make separate plots for each independent variable.

Comment: I want to have a single plot for both variables. I'm looking for that.

Comment: You could use `contour` or `scatterplot3d` to plot two independent variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ways to plot two variables. Since you did not provide data, I'll draw some from a data set included with R:

```
data(iris)
iris.sub <- subset(iris, subset=Species!="versicolor", select=c(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))
iris.sub <- droplevels(iris.sub)
set.seed(42)
iris.sub$Sepal.Length <- iris.sub$Sepal.Length + rnorm(100, 0, .5)
iris.sub$Sepal.Width <- iris.sub$Sepal.Width + rnorm(100, 0, .5)
str(iris.sub)
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 2 levels "setosa","virginica": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.79 4.62 4.88 4.92 5.2 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  4.1 3.52 2.7 4.02 3.27 ...
```

We need to drop one of the species for a logistic regression. Also the `iris` measurements overlap substantially so I've added some noise to them. This is what they look like:

```
clr <- as.numeric(iris.sub$Species) + 2
plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, iris.sub, pch=16, cex=1.5, col=clr)
legend("bottomleft", c("setosa", "virginica"), pch=16, cex=1.25, col=3:4)
```

[image: Plot 1]

Now the logistic regression:

```
iris.glm <- glm(Species~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width, iris.sub, family="binomial")
prob.vir <- predict(iris.glm, type="resp")
boxplot(prob.vir~Species, iris.sub, ylab="Probability virginica")
virginica <- as.numeric(iris.sub$Species) - 1
```

The box plot is just a double check to be sure that the predictions are for the second category `virginica`. Now we can plot each variable:

```
oldp <- par(mfcol=c(2, 1), mar=c(3.1, 4.1, 1.1, 2.1), mgp=c(2, 1, 0))
plot(virginica~Sepal.Length, iris.sub, ylab="Probability virginica", pch=16, col=clr)
x1 <- seq(min(iris.sub$Sepal.Length), max(iris.sub$Sepal.Length), length.out=50)
y1 <- predict(iris.glm, data.frame(Sepal.Length=x1, Sepal.Width=mean(iris.sub$Sepal.Width)), type="resp")
lines(x1, y1)

plot(virginica~Sepal.Width, iris.sub, ylab="Probability virginica", pch=16, col=clr)
x2 <- seq(min(iris.sub$Sepal.Width), max(iris.sub$Sepal.Width), length.out=50)
y2 <- predict(iris.glm, data.frame(Sepal.Width=x2, Sepal.Length=mean(iris.sub$Sepal.Length)), type="resp")
lines(x2, y2)
par(oldp)
```

[image: Plot 2]

The steep curve suggests a sharper break between the species and the gradual curve suggests a broader overlap. These curves are generated at the mean value for the variable not plotted. You could add curves at the quartiles for example to get more detail.

The `scatterplot3d` function can show both variables at once:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
plt <- scatterplot3d(iris.sub$Sepal.Length, iris.sub$Sepal.Width, predict(iris.glm, type="resp"),
     xlab="Sepal.Length", ylab="Sepal.Width", zlab="Probability of viginica",  
     scale.y=.75, angle=160, pch=16, color=clr)
surf <- function(x, y) predict(iris.glm, data.frame(Sepal.Length=x, Sepal.Width=y), type="resp")
plt$contour3d(surf, col="darkgray")
```

[image: Plot 3]

Finally, you can use a contour plot to show the boundary between the groups:

```
X <- expand.grid(x=x1, y=x2)
z <- predict(iris.glm, data.frame(Sepal.Length=X$x, Sepal.Width=X$y), type="resp")
plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, iris.sub, xlab="Sepal.Width", ylab="Sepal.Length", pch=16, col=clr)
legend("bottomleft", c("setosa", "virginica"), pch=16, cex=1.25, col=3:4)
contour(x2, x1, matrix(z, 50, 50, byrow=TRUE), levels=c(.05, .1, .5, .9, .95), add=TRUE)
```

[image: Plot 4]